# Prevent page break of full-text-area graphic inclusion

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, blank-page

I want to include a picture with width=\textwidth and height=\textheight. In the following MWE, the picture is not placed in the desired page. It produce one blank page first and then the picture. If I do not want the blank page what should I do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{picture.jpg}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you might try "reducing" the height of the graphic by preceding it (after a page break) by some negative `\vspace`.  start with `\vspace*{-1\baselineskip)` and increase the value gradually until the graphic stays on that page.  then you could "compensate" by splitting the negative space between the top and bottom of the page.

Comment: Just do `\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{picture.jpg}` as you can not set both sizes. If the aspect ratio is different to `\textwidth`/`\textheight`, your image will become too big for the page.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi if I only set the height, the picture will exceed the right text boundary.

Comment: you need `\noindent` as currently you are starting a paragraph with the image so it is indented by `\parindent` so you do not have `\textwidth` space

Comment: @LaRiFaRi you can set both sizes, it is not usual as it distorts the image, but if that's what you want, graphicx supports that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tested it with \noindent\includegraphics... but still not work

Comment: @SayOL you need noindent for horizontal, then for vertical you need as barbara said in initial comment `\vspace*{-something}`  tex is trying to put the baseline of the image `\topskip` below the top of the page

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it works! But I still do not understand why the picture goes the next page. It reasonably stay on that page because the width and height just fit the text area, not exceed.

Comment: as posted above both width and height of the text area are exceeded.

Comment: BTW, the \vspace*{-.95\baselineskip} is only needed on the first page for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example which creates a 1 page document in which the text area is filled by a suitably scaled A4 image.

I use `width=\textwidth, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio`. This means that the image will be as large as it can be subject to three constraints:

1. width not to exceed `\textwidth`,
2. height not to exceed `\textheight`
3. image not be be distorted i.e. the width and height will be scaled by the same factor if they require scaling.

[image: scaled image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,geometry}
\begin{document}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a4}
\end{document}
```

If you really want to use the entire page, rather than just the area reserved for the text block, you need a different approach:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,geometry,kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{scale=1}%
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{enfys}\thispagestyle{empty}
\restoregeometry
\kant[1-3]
\end{document}
```

This produces the following two pages of output shown as a double-page spread (but with the odd page on the left):

[image: full page image reverting to regular layout for Kant]

Comment: My picture dimensions is not proportional to the dimensions of the paper. So when I add option **keepaspectratio** it is not stretched to fit the whole text area.

Comment: @SayOL OK. Sorry... I don't see the problem. Either use `keepaspectratio` to prevent distortion or don't use it and the area will be filled but, of course, the disproportionate scaling will distort the image somewhat. I mean, there's no rule that you can't distort it. Just people don't usually want the distortion. If you don't mind, just omit the option. (I doubt it would matter with my rainbow, for example. If I were using that, distortion wouldn't really be an issue.)

Comment: for future users) Depends on what you want exactly, but if you want the image to silently overflow then `\vbox to \textheight{...}` the image instead.  It makes sense if the image jumps to the next page if there's already something on the page, but when the page is blank it isn't clear why the behavior isn't the default.